# The prototype (parent class) of a prototype object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, oop, prototype, prototype-programming

In Javascript, I can obtain the prototype of Array object by

```
var arr_prototype = Array.prototype
```

As I understand, this `Array.prototype` is similar to a Class in OOP.

In a pure OOP language, the `Array` class may inherit from `Iterable` class, and `Iterable` class may inherit from `Object` class.

So I wish to see the parent class of `arr_prototype` by eval the expression  `arr_prototype.prototype`.

However, it returns `undefined`. Does anyone have ideas about this?

Comment: you can get `prototype` property that refers to prototype only from _function_, otherwise you simple try get property with this name. to getting prototype from concrete object you can use [Object.getPrototypeOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf) function

Comment: When all else fails, [*read the spec*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-properties-of-the-array-prototype-object). Array.prototype inherits from Object.prototype, but is an instance of Array. It is an [*Array exotic object*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-array-exotic-objects), which is a little different to a standard Array object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(arr_prototype );
```

`prototype` property doesn't belong on the instance it belongs on the constructor